# Firebase, Android & C# : How to use the LimitToLast Function right?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having this issue, that there is nothing documented about C#. This is my code:

```
private async void DisplayChatMessage()
{
    lstMessage.Clear();

    var items = await firebase.Child(roomName).OnceAsync<MessageContent>();


    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        lstMessage.Add(item.Object);
    }

    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, lstMessage);
    lstChat.Adapter = adapter;

}
```

So, while I am doing this I am getting all childs from on room. (It is a chat application). Now, I can put this line into the code:

```
    FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference(roomName).LimitToLast(5);
```

However, this doenst limit anything.

All I want is to only download that last x messages from the chatroom.

Have you guys any idea?

THANKS :)

EDIT:

Im starting to get closer to the issue: 
In another link I found, someone did this:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/");
var dinos = await firebase
  .Child("dinosaurs")
  .OrderByKey()
  .StartAt("pterodactyl")
  .LimitToFirst(2)
  .OnceAsync<Dinosaur>();
```

SO, I am doing the EXACT same, yet I do NOT have these options after the string in child. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are missing a reference or a `using` statement to the namespace with those methods. Maybe something like `Firebase.Database`

Comment: that is true, i just found that out. The problem still is that I need to use the nuget packages that i already have...

Comment: okay nevermind. It was really just a missing using directiv. thanks!